# Implementing From trait without creating a copy

Tags: rust

I am rather inexperienced in Rust. It seems that using the approach bellow (that works!) creates a copy every time I convert between `Complexes` and `VecNumComplex`. Is there any suggestions to avoid making copies everytime?

```
// Complex is from the num crate. That's their definition:
// #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Hash, Debug, Default)]
// #[repr(C)]
// pub struct Complex<T> {
//    /// Real portion of the complex number
//    pub re: T,
//    /// Imaginary portion of the complex number
//    pub im: T,
//}

// Complexes and Robj come from extendr crate. SEXP is an object used //to communicate C with R.
//#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
//pub struct Complexes {
//    pub(crate) robj: Robj,
//}

//pub struct Robj {
//    inner: SEXP,
//}

pub struct VecNumComplex<T> {
    pub data: Vec<Complex<T>>
}

impl From<Complexes> for VecNumComplex<f64> {
    fn from(complexes: Complexes) -> Self {
        VecNumComplex { 
            data: complexes.iter().map(|x| Complex{ re: x.re().0, im: x.im().0 }).collect()
        }
    }
}

impl From<VecNumComplex<f64>> for Complexes {
    fn from(vecnumcomplex: VecNumComplex<f64>) -> Self {
        vecnumcomplex.data.iter().map(|x| Rcplx::from((x.re, x.im))).collect::<Complexes>()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Complex`? What is `Complexes`?

Comment: Sorry, added some more info... Hope it helps.

Comment: [I don't see a crate `extendr`](https://docs.rs/extendr).

Comment: https://github.com/extendr/extendr

Comment: They are with docs problem atm.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit more what you mean by "creates a copy every time"? A copy of what? Where do you observe the copy?

Comment: When I convert from a `Complexes` to a `VecNumComplex<f64>`, and vice versa, isn't it creating a copy?

Comment: Given that [`SEXP` is essentially a `void*`](https://docs.rs/libR-sys/latest/src/libR_sys/opt/rustwide/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/build/libR-sys-515f35c06d3a677c/out/bindings.rs.html#3194-3199) that's accessed through R FFI calls, there is no way to avoid copying when getting data to/from R.